Question Regarding Burnisdes Lemma In Combinatorics
I had the following problem in my book,

The number of ways in which a necklace can be formed using 6 identical diamonds and 3 identical pearls is.

I tried solving it and the first answer i got to was $1/9{9 \choose 3}$, this is obviously wrong as it is not even an integer, then i looked online for a solution, and found out that their is a general method for solving such problems, known as Burnsides Lemma, using articles and videos I found online i understood that to use it to solve a problem, you first count at the number of possible symmetrical actions, find the pictures which are invariant to each action, add them all up and them divide by the number of symmetries,
In the problem above i found the following symmetries,
1.Doing Nothing(identity): Pictures = 84
2.Shifting One Pearl/Diamond: Pictures = 0
Similarly for shifting 2, 3, 4, ... 9, all are zero,

Permuting the diamonds: Pictures are 6!

Permuting the diamonds: Pictures are 3!


5.Rotation: Pictures  = 9
Hence answer should be
$$\frac{84+9+3!+6!}{14}$$
which is again not an integer, i do not understand what i am doing wrong, any help would be highly appreciated.!

I dont get why there are no necklaces symmetrical under shifting. Let 0 denote diamond and 1 pearl, then the necklace 001001001 is symmetrical under the 3-shift.
Also the 14 seems off to me, the number of symmetries is 18 and not 14.

@schiepy Yeah i made some mistakes, but why are their 18 symmetries?

You have 9 shifts, and every such shift can be reflected giving 18 symmetries. This is called the dihedral group.

But how would i figure out the no. of pictures for each of these symmetries then?

There is a bit of a confusion about what mathematicians call a necklace. Usually, the number of necklaces is the number of strings where we group all those together that can be obtained by shifting the string. e.g. 010101 is the "same" as 101010.
I think the thing you want to count is the 3D version of that, where you can reflect/rotate the necklace as well. This is usually called a bracelet in combinatorics.
The group that describes these symmetries is called the dihedral group. If you google it you will find that the dihedral groups describe the symmetries of the regular $n$-gons, but we can view the necklace in your problem as an $9$-gon.
The dihedral group has the following elements:

The shifts, there are 9 of them (includes the symmetry of doing nothing)
The reflections, there are also 9 of them (depending on what your reflection axis is)

Since you want to use Burnside's Lemma we have to find the strings invariant under these symmetries. First there are $84$ necklaces total without grouping them together under symmetry.

Doing nothing: $84$ necklaces
Shifting (excluding the 9-shift/doing nothing): If the number of positions we shift is not 3 or 6 the number of invariant necklaces is 0. For both the 3 - and 6-shift the necklaces invariant under them are $100100100$, $010010010$ and $001001001$ (where 0=diamond and 1=pearl). Thus there are 3 for the 3-shift and 3 for the 6-shift, makes a total of $6$
Reflections: This is a bit tricky, so I include a picture 
Red means pearl and green means diamond. These are the four necklaces symmetrical under reflection with axis going through the top pearl. For every reflection there are only these 4 invariant necklaces, making a total of $4\cdot 9=36$.

This gives the total number of $$\frac{84+6+36}{18}=7.$$

Thanks for the answer!, loved it, one thing though why did we multiply the 4 cases which are symmetrical about the middle axis by 9?, and the reason we excluded nine shift is because it is the same thing as doing nothing right!

There are 9 reflections total and for every reflection there are 4 invariant necklaces. And yeah, the 9-shift is the same as doing nothing.

Thanks I understood it now!

Could we generalise this method say for n diamonds and 3 pearls?

There is a generalization of this method for any number of diamonds and pearls you can think of. Even more different objects than 2 are possible. However it becomes more complicated. The keyword is Pólya enumeration theorem.
